# Error while installing JQ of specific version

Tags: ubuntu, jq

I am trying to install JQ using below command but ends up in error when I don't provide the version the installation works fine. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS version.

```
sudo apt-get install jq=1.6
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.6' for 'jq' was not found
```

Comment: How about `1.6-2.1ubuntu3` ? See [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/jq)

Comment: @Raptor It worked for this version.why is this behavior ? . Even though in github repo i find 1.6 release nut still not able to install why ?

Comment: Ubuntu decides which [`jq` source to use for each suite](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jq&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).